# Como posso dar timeout em uma tentativa de conectar no SQL Server usando sqlalchemy?

Tags: python, sql-server, connectionstring, sqlalchemy

Tenho uma lista de 200 hosts para conectar. O problema é que quando eu tento conectar em um host que não está disponível, demora cerca de 10 segundos para eu receber uma exceção me dizendo que não conectou. Porém quando conecta demora menos de 1 segundo para conectar.

Queria algo parecido com isso:

```
if(engine.connect() > 1 segundo) para de tentar conectar
```

Eu tentei

```
 create_engine(db_url, connect_args={'connect_timeout': 1})
```

Não funcionou.

Eu estou usando sqlachemy, tentando conectar em SQL Server

Obrigado

Comment: Por favor, traduza sua pergunta. Você está no stackoverflow em português

Answer (score 1):

Para `SQL Server` o parametro correto é `Remote Query Timeout`

```
create_engine(db_url, connect_args={'Remote Query Timeout': 1})
```

Comment: Tentei isso, mas agora da erro em todas conexões com a exceção "Remote Query Timeout" :(